# labelling residuals

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have made a linear regression model in R with 3 continuous independent variables and one continuous dependent variable. I have generated the diagnostic plots. 
I would now like to label/colour the data points for each residual on my diagnostic plots according to the binary categorical independent variable that was not included in the model ie when this variable = A, I want a blue dot on my diagnostic plot, when this variable = B, I want a red dot. So there will be red and blue dots on my diagnostic plots. 
I would love some advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the standard diagnostic plots from plot.lm, you can use the following:

```
x<-rnorm(100); y<-2*x+rnorm(100)
fit<-lm(y~x)
grp<-rep(c("A","B"),c(50,50))
color<-ifelse(grp=="A",2,4)
plot(fit,id.n=length(x),labels.id=grp,col=color)
```

you should check out `?plot.lm`